# CollisionOnEnter how to detect if an object is colliding?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics

im pretty new to C# and Unity and i try to make an Angry Birds clone, and im stuck on this problem.

I want to change the mass of the mass of the Gameobject(in my case the woodblock) when the bird is flying and hits the object, it should change from Mass: 1 to Mass: 0.2
[here is a screenshot of the scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkvYa.png)
I created two Methods and it works in a weird way but every time i start the game the Mass gets not to 1 rather in 0.2. It should only change when the bird collides with the woodblock.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Wall : MonoBehaviour

private float wallMass;
private bool isHit;
private Rigidbody2D rb;

void Start()
{
    rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    wallMass = 1.0f;
    isHit = false;
}

void Update()
{
    CollisionOn(isHit);
}

private void CollisionOn(bool isTrue)
{
    rb.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().mass = wallMass;
    if (isTrue)
    {
        DecreaseMass();
    }
}

void DecreaseMass()
{
    rb.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().mass = 0.2f;
}
```

Comment: Usually when doing colission you have to check every object against every other object every single Update/game tick. Of course it could be that Unity has some automagic to takes this from you, and instead gives you a Event or Pollable property on objects to check who colided with whom.

Comment: "but every time i start the game the Mass gets not to 1 rather in 0.2." Could you please rewrite that? I'm really not sure what you want to say here. Also where do you set your `isHit` to true? And the paramter in `CollisionOn` should not be named `isTrue` as it also can be false, I guess.

Comment: You don't need to check on each frame if the collision occured. Unity provide events that triggers when there's a collision. Check [this](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/3d-physics#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b515)

Comment: Surely you just use "OnCollisionEnter" and "OnCollisionExit" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these 2 events on a MonoBehaviour, that's attached to the box.

Called when collision occurs

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
   GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().mass = wallMass;
}
```

Same way when Collision ends.

```
void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
{
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().mass = 0.2f;
}
```